# Silent Install specific application version using Chef

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, version, silent-installer

I am able to install an array of different programs silently. However I am unable to install ConEmu as the normal .exe link (Which is used in the source " " code below) will break the silent install by asking the User which version they want to download.

```
 #install ConEmu
 windows_package 'ConEmu' do
 installer_type :custom
 retries 2
 options " /S /D=D:\\Home\\Apps\\ConEmu"
 source  ""
 action :install
end
```

I am unsure as to what if any code can be inserted within the options code. The version options prompt appears with the destination correctly set "D:\Home\Apps\ConEmu". The version choices are 170819x64 or 170819x86.

If anyone has any suggestions or experience please let me know. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

When using a custom installer type, all Chef can do is run the program and hope for the best. It's up to you to make sure to give all the options needed to ensure headless operation. I would double check if they offer an MSI instead, or if a NuGet package exists somewhere.